What Robotics competitions exists for middle and high school level?
I am running a robotics club and we used to compete in the first lego league (fll). We are looking for a competition for high school kids and an alternative for fll for the middle school age group. I found the World robotics Olympiad but have difficulties finding specifics about budget needed and schedule for the season and local competitions.
Our biggest problem with fll is the project that is usually not robotics based. We know about the benefits of the project part for the competition but usually run out of time and we are loosing kids interest.
What are the available competition? We are wisconsin based so competitions in our region are preferred. Also lego based competitions are a plus since we are already invested in the technology.

your question is not really about a robotics problem

but with so little information out there, I hoped to get some contact/direction.

For high schoolers, check out FIRST Robotics and the Wikipedia article. FIRST organizes robot competitions among thousands of teams worldwide.  Those pages summarize the program far better than I can do right here. FRC robots absolutely do not meet your Lego desideratum! The club will need some fundraising and some mentors (for whom there is extensive peer help!).
Also on the Wikipedia page, check out the several other FIRST programs that do use Lego. I don't really know anything about them.
Maybe your crew is into tinkering more than organized competition. For minimum budget, I'd suggest TT gearbox motors (zillions on Amazon), little ESP32 boards (which include WiFi and Bluetooth), with foamcore, X-Acto knife, and a hot glue gun for structurals. There is an Arduino setup for ESP32 but I'd recommend MicroPython.
The FRC team I was a mentor for, 7795 Norse Code, was started by two H.S. Juniors, both girls. They persevered and eventually persuaded the school to grant official club status, which allowed use of the school building, stipend for a teacher mentor, and access to support ($$$) from local foundations.
Good luck to your team, Peter!

I believe the two largest robotics competitions for you to be:

FIRST https://www.firstinspires.org/robotics/frc
VEX https://www.vexrobotics.com/

